# Making vertical separator css

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I need help with making double vertical lines.

[image: Problem]

Here are styles:

```
.slide-container
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}

.v-separator
{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 230px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fafafa;
    border-left: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

`.v-separator` has width 2px because of border and this causes the problem. I have tried to make `.slide-container` width a bit less than 25% (like 23.853%), but this is not the decision.

I have no idea how to implement this feature somehow else.

Btw I am using Foundation 5 and Compass.

fiddle which demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5w7Hr/

Comment: @Harry "horisontal" was a typo. I am trying to make double vertical line (like I did on the picture) which can fit here. Maybe I can't explain the problem clearly, because I am very tired with it.

Comment: @VIRUS can you create a fiddle for your code?

Comment: Please share your HTML too.

Comment: @Harry, I need to make "double" border without any spacing between two lines and with two different colors. Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5w7Hr/

Comment: @VIRUS: Ok, got it. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5w7Hr/1/) fine?

Comment: @Harry: Good shot. Just had [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/mktBa/1/) one...

Comment: This is a duplicate of so, so many questions.

Comment: Now I don't even know which of the examples is better to use. Ty guys, it seems to be very simple :)

Comment: @Nit I knew it. I have had a look at some searching results but they didn't help. Well, it is better to ask than search a lot.

Comment: @Nit If you think the question is a duplicate, please find an existing question to vote to close or at least link to for users that have the Rep to vote on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `width:25%` generally doesn't include the margins and borders. When all these are added together the width exceeds 100%. This is the reason why the last box gets pushed down. You can fix this by adding `box-sizing` setting as shown below.

**Note:** Elements whose display is `inline-block` by default have a margin assigned and hence we have to offset that also by assigning a negative margin (Source: [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)). Alternately, using `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block` is also a good option.

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 600px;
    background: lime;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px -4px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w7Hr/1/)

Comment: Instead of answering a duplicate question it's better to simply flag it.

Comment: @Nit: Am I to assume that you were the one who down-voted? In which case wouldn't it have been better just to flag the question? If the question gets removed then the answer goes with it too. Downvoting an answer for this reason makes the answer look as though it is wrong. As of now, I see no close/duplicate votes on the question.

Comment: @Harry By the way, like in my example the problem appears again if u  try to zoom-in or zoom-out the page.

Comment: @VIRUS: Actually the reason is because we are assigning 25% for all 4 divs (100%) and there is extra 2px in border for every separator and hence using the CSS3 `calc` function would make it very easy like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5w7Hr/3/). This seems to work well on zomming also.

Comment: @Harry yeah, I understand that those line don't simply fit there. If only I could write `width: 25%-2px` without any tricky features it would be perfect.

Comment: @VIRUS: Thats exactly what the `calc` function does (25% - 2px). Check that fiddle demo that I posted in previous comment. Note: The demo would have it as `-webkit-calc` because my browser is outdated :D

Comment: Hm... In my project the problem didn't disappear and i guess that i know why. I found out that `border: 1px ...` becomes 4px (!) width when i zoom-out

Comment: @VIRUS: Check this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5w7Hr/4/). It has the double colored border like you want, needs no separate element for the vertical separator, can support width of 25% and works while zooming also.

Comment: note that the default margin between `inline-block` elements is dependent of parent element's font-size. It has the width of a space char.